# Weight paint not showing weights for right bone

Tags: armature, weight-painting

My shoulder bone is selected but the weights for the head bone is showing like this[image]

No matter what bone I select, it always shows the weight for the head bone. When I paint over it, the effects are reversed like adding subtracts weight and vice versa .The weights of the shoulder are affected. Is it supposed to work that way?

Comment: You have weights on the wrong bone, the weights are displayed only for the selected bone.

Comment: First, I selected the head bone, painted my weights on, then selected the shoulder bone. Did I switch bones wrong or something like that?

Comment: Do you use the same mesh for the head and shoulder bones? Because if it is, then both head and shoulder bones will affect the movements of that mesh